# Crystals and charge

Tags: piezoelectric

I've been researching on Piezoelectric crystals. And i've been wondering that could keeping constant pressure on piezoelectric crystals create a constant flow of electricity?

*I've tried googling it but the results were off topic.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A very loose analogy would be pushing on the plunger of a syringe. You get a squirt of water out, but not a continuous flow.

In a piezoelectric crystal, squeezing the crystal distorts the shape of the crystal a little in a way that separates charges. This doesn't break any bonds. It just stretches them so that positive charges are, say, moved a little to the left and negative a little to the right. If you have a wire connecting the two ends of the crystal, the negative end of the crystal repels electrons and the positive end attracts them. Electrons are pushed through the wire until the charges balance.

Comment: Thank you that actually makes sense.